# docker image is not running

Tags: docker, sbt, sbt1.0

i have created a custom image of my sbt project here is the docker file

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8

MAINTAINER name <email>


RUN echo "==> fetch all sbt jars from Maven repo..."       && \
    echo "==> [CAUTION] this may take several minutes!!!"  && \
    sbt publishLocal


WORKDIR /test-commons


# Define default command.
ENTRYPOINT ["sbt publishLocal"]
CMD ["sbt publishLocal"]
```

then i build it

```
docker build .
```

and `docker ps` returning

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG                   IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
test-commons              v1                    8adba9557f57        12 minutes ago      1.05GB
```

and `docker run test-commons:v1`
is giving

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"sbt publishLocal\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0007] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I am a begginer in this please guide what am i missing here

Answer (score 0):

Using just `CMD` would be sufficient, remove the redundant `ENTRYPOINT` statement  & try -

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8

MAINTAINER name <email>


RUN echo "==> fetch all sbt jars from Maven repo..."       && \
    echo "==> [CAUTION] this may take several minutes!!!"  && \
    sbt publishLocal


WORKDIR /test-commons


CMD ["sbt", "publishLocal"]
```

Comment: @swaheed - Where is `sbt` executable located? Share the absolute path.